# find exact word as part of a string

Tags: sqlite

I need to write a single SQL statement to list all the tracks that have the exact word 'right' (including both upper and lower cases) as part of the name in a table called Track. In other words, it will NOT include track names with words like 'rights' or 'righteous' in the output

I wrote this but I keep getting words with letters before or after right eg: brighter or rights.

```
SELECT name

FROM Track

WHERE name LIKE "%right%";
```

Comment: You need to do a MATCH. First you build a FTS table then do a MATCH. To use FTS table you need to define SQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3 in your SQLITE lib. MATCH works on whole word and it is not case sensitive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[LIKE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp) is for pattern matching. `%` means "zero or more characters of anything" like a `*` wildcard in other systems. `name LIKE "%right%"` says "name is the word 'right' with anything before and after it". That's why you're getting "brighter" and "rights".

With a regular expression you could write something like `/\bright\b/` where `\b` means "word break". But SQLite requires a plugin to use regexes and `LIKE` has no equivalent. All you have to work with is `%` (zero or more characters) or `_` (any one character). Best you can do is match spaces such as `LIKE "% right %"` but that only works if there are spaces around "right". "right now" won't match.

If you want to pick the word "right" out of values like "right left" and "turn right" and "left right left" you need to cover four possibilities.

- It's at the start.
- It's at the end.
- It's in the middle.
- It's alone.

This means four expressions.

```
name LIKE "right %"   or
name LIKE "% right"   or
name LIKE "% right %" or
lower(name) = "right"
```

`LIKE` in SQLite is case-insensitive by default. `=` is not, so `lower(name)` is necessary to normalize the value to lower case.

Comment: I don't think he is looking for equality. if name field contains "RIGHT MAN" then he wants that name to be in output. but according to your answer that wont give the output right?

Comment: Thanks the = seems to just give me nothing because there are no track titles with just RIGHT in it. I tried that before posting and got it. I am needing to get it with other words but also have the criteria of no  letters before or after..... does that make sense Schwern?

Comment: @DeendayalGarg That does make more sense! I've updated my answer.